# Retrieve a reference to JPA transaction

Tags: jpa, spring-transactions

I'm trying to commit JPA manually

```
    var tx = em.getTransaction();

    for(var key : aggrFornitore.keySet()){
        tx.begin();
        try {
            var righe = aggrFornitore.get(key);
            jpaOperatingOnRepositories(key, righe, mSchede, mSettings);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
```

em is:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

JPA thorws an exception

```
Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
```

Is it possible to control JPA transaction manager manually?

Thanks to xerx593 comment I changed my code into

```
   for(var key : aggrFornitore.keySet()){
        var txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        txDef.setIsolationLevel(DefaultTransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
        TransactionStatus transactionStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(txDef);

        try {
            var righe = aggrFornitore.get(key);
            creaSingoloOrdine(key, righe, mSchede, mSettings);
            transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            transactionManager.rollback(transactionStatus);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Spring has instructions on getting the sprint data jpa transaction manager. What type of object is a `righe`. You want me to be a compiler?

Comment: As the error message implies: use `org.spring...` transactions ... (or "container managed tx" ...not jpa/jta) https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management